# How can I improve the accuracy of my neural network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, voice-recognition, tflearn

I am trying to build a simple neural network to recognize 14 words from the voice of 2 people.

I created a train dataset containing 2471 files with a length of 0.5 s (8000 Hz) and a test dataset containing 612 files.

I used "Short-time Fourier transform" like this:

```
_, _, d = signal.stft(d, 8000, nperseg=400) 
d = numpy.abs(d)
```

The spectrogram of example file:

[image]

And this is my network:

```
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 201, 21])

net = tflearn.max_pool_1d(net, 8)
net = tflearn.conv_1d(net, 128, 6, activation='relu')
net = tflearn.avg_pool_1d(net, 4)

net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 128, activation='relu')
net = tflearn.dropout(net, 0.6)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 14, activation='softmax')

net = tflearn.regression(net, optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', learning_rate=0.02)

# Train model

model = tflearn.DNN(net)
model.fit(X, Y, n_epoch=12, validation_set=(X_test, Y_test), show_metric=True)
```

I tried to change many parameters, but the accuracy of the network is still around 90%

```
| Adam | epoch: 011 | loss: 0.34011 - acc: 0.9428 | val_loss: 0.23105 - val_acc: 0.9003
| Adam | epoch: 012 | loss: 0.37237 - acc: 0.9253 | val_loss: 0.22360 - val_acc: 0.9118
```

After 100 epochs:

```
| Adam | epoch: 088 | loss: 0.21640 - acc: 0.9753 | val_loss: 0.24923 - val_acc: 0.9297
| Adam | epoch: 099 | loss: 0.48295 - acc: 0.9469 | val_loss: 0.28505 - val_acc: 0.9346
| Adam | epoch: 100 | loss: 0.56168 - acc: 0.9489 | val_loss: 0.24747 - val_acc: 0.9395
```

After 500 epochs:

```
| Adam | epoch: 485 | loss: 0.20620 - acc: 0.9795 | val_loss: 0.41541 - val_acc: 0.9265
| Adam | epoch: 493 | loss: 0.48699 - acc: 0.9559 | val_loss: 0.23821 - val_acc: 0.9248 -- iter: 4942/4942
| Adam | epoch: 499 | loss: 0.69429 - acc: 0.9501 | val_loss: 0.39483 - val_acc: 0.8987
| Adam | epoch: 500 | loss: 0.87411 - acc: 0.9394 | val_loss: 0.36144 - val_acc: 0.9248
```

Can anyone tell me what I can change to get better results? What am I doing wrong ?

Increasing the number of neurons or epochs does not improve the result

Comment: You may need way more epochs to achieve better accuracy.

Comment: Well, now you're getting better accuracy. 500 epochs may be even better, but you don't really need 100% accuracy all the time as you may need your network to be more creative.

Comment: And what about the structure. Is it OK?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here, although the dropout rate may be a bit too high.

Comment: Accuracy did not increase :( However, when I try to recognize my voice live, the network has a problem with some words.

Comment: Have you analyzed the cases that it gets wrong? Going through the error cases by hand in detail will often reveal issues in the data that you weren't aware of. It may also give you direction in which path to take towards improvement.

Comment: Yes i checked but i didn't see any issues :/

Answer (score 0):

Optimal speech architectures are slightly different from what you are trying. What you probably need to experiment with: data mean normalization (CMN), recurrent network or transformer-like network with attention. For more details on proper speech recognition architecture you can best entries of [Kaggle Speech Recognition Challenge](https://www.kaggle.com/c/tensorflow-speech-recognition-challenge/discussion)